# check html checkbox using a button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling to find a solution for this anywhere on Google, maybe i'm searching incorrectly but thought I would come and ask the ever trustworthy members of StackOverflow.

I'm wanting to use an html button to check an html check box. There reason I don't want to use the check box will be purely for accessibility reasons because the application i'm developing will be on a terminal and used as via a touch-screen so an HTML check box is too small.

The only issue is that the list of check box's is dynamic as it is populated using an SQL query. Obviously however I can do the same for creating HTML buttons.

Im guessing it will require JavaScript (which I'm perfectly happy using now as I'm finding a lot of the functionality I need in this application needs JavaScript) to do this functionality.

So to clarify: I want to click on a button, say it has a value of "Fin Rot" and that checks the check box with the value "Fin Rot". And then if I clicked another button, say it has a value of "Ich" then it also checks the check box with the value "Ich"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While you *can* use a button and JavaScript for this, might I suggest a much simpler approach?  Just use a `<label>` that's designed *just* for this, and style it like a button, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="finRot" name="something" value="Fin Rot">
<label for="finRot">Some text here, could be "Fin Rot"</label>
```

or (if you don't want to use `id` on `checkbox` and `for` on `label`):

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="something" value="Fin Rot">
    Some text here, could be "Fin Rot"
</label>
```

....then with CSS you can hide the checkbox if needed, but either are clickable to toggle the checkbox.

[You can test out a demo here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Gf83S/), also showing some button-ish CSS on the label if needed.

Comment: +1 so much better than the JS-based solution I was writing when you posted this...

Comment: @Felix - nope, that's the `for` attribute piece...works since Netscape :)

Comment: @Felix: it works for me (Chrome 8.x, Ubuntu 10.10) so long as the value of the 'for' attribute is exactly the same as the `id` of the relevant `input` element.

Comment: @Nick Craver, @David Thomas: Oh I just copied Nick's code and it was still `id"finRot"`... never mind then ;)

Comment: @Felix - typo! I thought I caught it fast :'(

Comment: @Nick: I think when I opened this question your answer was like "answered 0 secs ago" :D Anyway, we can delete all these senseless comments ;)

Comment: Once again the members of StackOverflow have come through for me... thanks "vishwanath" and "Dutchie342" for your suggestions also. Nick I have gone with the solution you provided on your link as it provides me with some customisation options via the CSS. Thank you very much. I'll mark this as answer

Comment: This causes some problems in connection with accessibility, in particular when moving using the tab-index, user is not able to mark the checkbox as checked.

Answer (score 2):

This example uses a button to toggle the checkbox on/off.

http://jsfiddle.net/DnEL3/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="finRot" name="something" value="Fin Rot">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('finRot').checked=!document.getElementById('finRot').checked;">Fin Rot</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a HTML solution.

```
 <p><input type="checkbox"
 value="Another check box"
 name="cboxwithlabel" id="idbox"><label
 for="idbox">Another
 checkbox</label></p>
```

<label>  Creates label for the checkbox or radio buttons.

Comment: Or, indeed, any other `input` (and `textarea`) element... =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for bootstrap solution, I just created this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <!-- Here starts the component -->
      <label class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="checkbox">
        </span>
        <span class="form-control btn btn-primary">
          Click to toggle checkbox
        </span>
      </label>
      <!-- Here ends the component -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you realise this post is 9 years old now right??

Comment: I know.. And still google managed to point me to this post. So I thought it might be useful to share my approach as a reference for potential visitiors.