# Make radio label active on touch mobile devices

Tags: html, radio-button, touch, label

I have made an html wizzard for making order. There are four steps, in each is bunch of radio buttons. I redesigned each radio button label to large button (and hidding the radio input itself). This all work greatly on classic PC. But I've run into problem with mobile device (iPHONE & iPAD, I can't test it on other devices, because I don't have any), which are unable to select the radio button.

I've found only [one notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639572/check-html-checkbox-using-a-button) of this problem here on stackoverflow, but the solution published there isn't function either.

The original inspiration comes from [apple online store](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_ipad/family/ipad/select_ipad) for selecting differnt color of device.

My example code:

```html
<label class="option" for="edit-term-worker">
  <input id="edit-term-worker" class="form-radio" type="radio">
  <span class="worker-name">Sandra</span>
</label>
```

It's there need some JS, or I'have some flaw in my code?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<input id="edit-term-worker" class="form-radio" type="radio" />
<label class="option" for="edit-term-worker"  onclick="">
<span class="worker-name">Sandra</span>
</label>
```

EDIT: Added an empty onclick, according to this that should do the trick: [HTML <label> command doesn't work in Iphone browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421659/html-label-command-doesnt-work-in-iphone-browser)

Note that you shouldn't put the radio button into the label tag, it should be outside.

Comment: Worked for me too. Will work if you put it on the form element as well if you want to minimise inline javascript, but I got a better click/reveal result from putting it on each label.

Comment: Very weird behaviour but it worked for me too - just add onclick="" to your labels and the entire label becomes clickable. Stupid iPad.